# How to integrate KML file with Google Maps API using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've used Google Maps API in the past and published a KML file using html.

However, I've been learning about customizing Google Maps using javascript (I'm new to JS - total beginner) using this tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/custom-interactive-maps-with-the-google-maps-api

**What I'm wondering is if anyone can explain how to incorporate the KML file into a customized map** using the approach described in the tutorial. The source files are accessible here: https://github.com/tutsplus/google-maps-api

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial for KML layers in the official documentation. Take a look at the

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml

Hope this helps!